# Wrapper to FOR loops with progress bar

Tags: function, r, loops, expression, wrapper

I like to use a progress bar while running slow `for` loops. This could be done easily with several helpers, but I do like the `tkProgressBar` from *tcltk* package.

A small example:

```
pb <- tkProgressBar(title = "Working hard:", min = 0, max = length(urls), width = 300)
for (i in 1:300) {
    # DO SOMETHING
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    setTkProgressBar(pb, i, label=paste( round(i/length(urls)*100, 0), "% ready!"))
}
close(pb)
```

And I would like to set up a small function to store in my *.Rprofile* named to `forp` (as: for loop with progressbar), to call just like `for` but with auto added progress bar - but unfortunately have no idea how to implement and grab the `expr` part of the loop function. I had some experiments with `do.call` but without success :(

Imaginary working example (which acts like a `for` loop but creates a `TkProgressBar` and auto updates it in each iteration):

```
forp (i in 1:10) {
    #do something
}
```

**UPDATE**: I think the core of the question is how to write a function which not only has parameters in the parentheses after the function (like: `foo(bar)`), but also can handle `expr` specified after the closing parentheses, like: `foo(bar) expr`.

---

**BOUNTY OFFER**: would go to any answer that could modify [my suggested function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349570/wrapper-to-for-loops-with-progress-bar/7354293#7354293) to work like the syntax of basic `for` loops. E.g. instead of

```
> forp(1:1000, {
+   a<-i
+ })
> a
[1] 1000
```

it could be called like:

```
> forp(1:1000) {
+   a<-i
+ }
> a
[1] 1000
```

**Just to clarify the task again**: how could we grab the `{ expression }` part of a function call? I am afraid that this is not possible, but will leave on the bounty for a few days for the pros :)

Comment: Can we add something between the `forp` and the expression, like `forp(1:1000) %do% { expression }`?  If so, it should be similar to what the `foreach` package does, and maybe even could be used directly.  I don't think you can do it without adding that, but am open to being corrected.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron for your comment. I hope there could be some kind of solution without extra tweaks in syntax. If not, then the working function below will be just fine without any modification.

Comment: We'll see if anyone comes forward with a way with no modification; in the meantime, I did code up my above suggestion, which at least only needs modification at the top of the loop (no extra `)` at the end, that is).

Comment: That is cool @Aaron, thanks! If there won't be a solution to escape even a small modification, then the bounty will go to you :)

Comment: You are trying to modify the language. I would be very careful with this... You may forgot many things (like break/continue statements etc.) and prepare ground for future mystery-errors. Be careful with that.

Comment: @Tomas, I think the spirit of the question is more "Can I do this without modifying the language, and if not, how close can I get?"  I don't think @daroczig is looking to get into the R source and make a new `forp` command, though it does seem that would be the only way to precisely do what he's hoping for.

Answer (score 6):

Given the other answers supplied, I suspect that it is <del>impossible</del> tough to do in exactly the way you specify.

However, I believe there is a way of getting very close, if you use the `plyr` package creatively.  The trick is to use `l_ply` which takes a list as input and creates no output.

The only real differences between this solution and your specification is that in a `for` loop you can directly modify variables in the same environment.  Using `l_ply` you need to send a function, so you will have to be more careful if you want to modify stuff in the parent environment.

Try the following:

```
library(plyr)
forp <- function(i, .fun){
  l_ply(i, .fun, .progress="tk")
}

a <- 0
forp(1:100, function(i){
  Sys.sleep(0.01)
  a<<-a+i
  })
print(a)
[1] 5050
```

This creates a progress bar and modifies the value of `a` in the global environment.

---

**EDIT.**

For the avoidance of doubt:  The argument `.fun` will always be a function with  a single argument, e.g. `.fun=function(i){...}`.

For example:

`for(i in 1:10){expr}` is equivalent to `forp(1:10, function(i){expr})`

In other words:

- `i` is the looping parameter of the loop
- `.fun` is a function with a single argument `i`

Comment: This does look like a nice version of my pseudocode answer.  But: what happens if you want to run an existing function of more than one variable?   `lply(i, myfunc(x,y))`  isn't going to work so far as I can tell.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft And that's OK, isn't it?  Since you can only ever have one variable in a for loop.  Any other variables are simply referred to inside the body of the function... Because of scoping up the call stack it will work - in exactly the same way as a for loop.

Comment: Andrie, I think I see yr point.  `i <- c(1,3,5,6,7,8,9); forp(i,myfunc(x=i,y))` is the way it would work.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a neat solution with some compromise (+1). Unfortunately it is bit far from what I am after, but it seems that my goal is unattainable.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I am not sure that will work.  I have edited my answer to give a bit more detail.  The equivalent to `for(i in seq(1, 9, by=2){expr}` would be `forp(i=seq(1, 9, by=2), .fun=function(i){expr})`.  In other words, `.fun` will always be a function with only a single argument.

Answer (score 6):

My solution is very similar to Andrie's except it uses base R, and I second his comments on the need to wrap what you want to do in a function and the subsequent need to use `<<-` to modify stuff in a higher environment.

Here's a function that does nothing, and does it slowly:

```
myfun <- function(x, text) {
  Sys.sleep(0.2)
  cat("running ",x, " with text of '", text, "'\n", sep="")
  x
}
```

Here's my `forp` function.  Note that regardless of what we're actually looping over, it instead loops over the sequence `1:n` instead and get the right term of what we actually want within the loop. `plyr` does this automatically.

```
library(tcltk)
forp <- function(x, FUN, ...) {
  n <- length(x)
  pb <- tkProgressBar(title = "Working hard:", min = 0, max = n, width = 300)
  out <- vector("list", n)
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    out[[i]] <- FUN(x[i], ...)
    setTkProgressBar(pb, i, label=paste( round(i/n*100, 0), "% ready!"))
  }
  close(pb)
  invisible(out)
}
```

And here's how both `for` and `forp` might be used, if all we want to do is call `myfun`:

```
x <- LETTERS[1:5]
for(xi in x) myfun(xi, "hi")
forp(x, myfun, text="hi")
```

And here's how they might be used if we want to modify something along the way.

```
out <- "result:"
for(xi in x) {
  out <- paste(out, myfun(xi, "hi"))
}

out <- "result:"
forp(x, function(xi) {
    out <<- paste(out, myfun(xi, "hi"))
})
```

For both versions the result is

```
> out
[1] "result: A B C D E"
```

EDIT: After seeing your (daroczig's) solution, I have another idea that might not be quite so unwieldy, which is to evaluate the expression in the parent frame.  This makes it easier to allow for values other than `i` (now specified with the `index` argument), though as of right now I don't think it handles a function as the expression, though just to drop in instead a for loop that shouldn't matter.

```
forp2 <- function(index, x, expr) {
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  n <- length(x)
  pb <- tkProgressBar(title = "Working hard:", min = 0, max = n, width = 300)
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    assign(index, x[i], envir=parent.frame())
    eval(expr, envir=parent.frame())
    setTkProgressBar(pb, i, label=paste( round(i/n*100, 0), "% ready!"))
  }
  close(pb)
}
```

The code to run my example from above would be

```
out <- "result:"
forp2("xi", LETTERS[1:5], {
    out <- paste(out, myfun(xi, "hi"))
})
```

and the result is the same.

ANOTHER EDIT, based on the additional information in your bounty offer:

The syntax `forX(1:1000) %doX$ { expression }` is possible; that's what the `foreach` package does.  I'm too lazy right now to build it off of your solution, but building off mine, it could look like this:

```
`%doX%` <- function(index, expr) {
  x <- index[[1]]
  index <- names(index)
  expr <- substitute(expr)
  n <- length(x)
  pb <- tkProgressBar(title = "Working hard:", min = 0, max = n, width = 300)
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    assign(index, x[i], envir=parent.frame())
    eval(expr, envir=parent.frame())
    setTkProgressBar(pb, i, label=paste( round(i/n*100, 0), "% ready!"))
  }
  close(pb)
  invisible(out)
}

forX <- function(...) {
  a <- list(...)
  if(length(a)!=1) {
    stop("index must have only one element")
  }
  a
}
```

Then the use syntax is this, and the result is the same as above.

```
out <- "result:"
forX(xi=LETTERS[1:5]) %doX% {
  out <- paste(out, myfun(xi, "hi"))
}
out
```

Comment: Thank you Aaron, that is great too (+1). Does not perfectly fit my demand, but close :)

Comment: Thank you Aaron again, especially for the updated script. As I wrote before, if we cannot find a "perfect" solution, than the bounty should be awarded to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `plyr` family of commands instead of a for loop (generally a good idea if possible), you get as an added bonus a whole system of progress bars.

`R.utils` also has some progress bars built into it, and there exist [instructions for using them in for loops](http://ryouready.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/r-monitor-function-progress-with-a-progress-bar/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer: `plyr` is a really great tool in most of the time, but I definitely need `for` loops sometimes (with complex structures where data is spread in several datasets). Unfortunately the linked resource just show an example like I entered in my question, so just several manual ways of adding a progress bar to a `for` loop, but no ideas of an automatic progress bar what I am after (with e.g. `forp` function).

Answer (score 3):

R's syntax doesn't let you do exactly what you want, ie:

```
forp (i in 1:10) {
    #do something
}
```

But what you can do is create some kind of iterator object and loop using while():

```
while(nextStep(m)){sleep.milli(20)}
```

Now you have the problem of what `m` is and how you make `nextStep(m)` have side effects on `m` in order to make it return `FALSE` at the end of your loop. I've written simple iterators that do this, as well as MCMC iterators that let you define and test for a burnin and thinning  period within your loop.

Recently at the R User conference I saw someone define a 'do' function that then worked as an operator, something like:

```
do(100) %*% foo()
```

but I'm not sure that was the exact syntax and I'm not sure how to implement it or who it was put that up... Perhaps someone else can remember!

Comment: Your latter example looks similar to the `foreach` syntax from the foreach package.

Comment: Thank you @Spacedman too! I am not sure right now how your suggestions can help me to make up a `forp` function, but will try to catch up :) Will report back.

Answer (score 3):

What you're hoping for, I think would be something that looks like

```
body(for)<- as.call(c(as.name('{'),expression([your_updatebar], body(for))))
```

And yep, the problem is that "for" is not a function, or at least not one whose "body" is accessible.  You could, I suppose, create a "forp" function that takes as arguments 1) a string to be turned into the loop counter, e.g.,  `" ( i in seq(1,101,5) )"` , and 2) the body of your intended loop, e.g., `y[i]<- foo[i]^2 ; points(foo[i],y[i]`,  and then jump thru some getcallparse magic to execute the actual for loop.
Then , in pseudocode (not close to actual R code, but I think you see what should happen)

```
forp<-function(indexer,loopbody) {
```

`pseudoparse( c("for (", indexer, ") {" ,loopbody,"}") 
}`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the for-loop in R is treated special. A normal function is not allowed to look like that. Some small tweaks can make it loop pretty close though. And as @Aaron mentioned, the **foreach** package's `%dopar%` paradigm seems like the best fit. Here's my version of how it could work:

```
`%doprogress%` <- function(forExpr, bodyExpr) {
   forExpr <- substitute(forExpr)
   bodyExpr <- substitute(bodyExpr)

   idxName <- names(forExpr)[[2]]
   vals <- eval(forExpr[[2]])

   e <- new.env(parent=parent.frame())

   pb <- tkProgressBar(title = "Working hard:", min = 0, max = length(vals), width = 300)
   for (i in seq_along(vals)) {
     e[[idxName]] <- vals[[i]]
     eval(bodyExpr, e)
     setTkProgressBar(pb, i, label=paste( round(i/length(vals)*100, 0), "% ready!"))
   }
}


# Example usage:

foreach(x = runif(10)) %doprogress% { 
  # do something
  if (x < 0.5) cat("small\n") else cat("big")
}
```

As you can see, you have to type `x = 1:10` instead of `x in 1:10`, and the infix operator `%<whatever>%` is needed to get hold of the looping construct and the loop body. I currently don't do any error checking (to avoid muddling the code). You should check the name of the function (`"foreach"`), the number of arguments to it (`1`) and that you actually get a valid loop variable (`"x"`) and not an empty string.

Comment: If you choose to use `foreach` directly, I'd suggest also using the iteration function in the `foreach` package, `iter`; similarly to `foreach:::doSEQ`.

Comment: Thanks Tommy, that is cool also. As @Aaron was faster and especially for `%doX%` being shorter than `%doprogress%` the bounty goes to him :) I can only award you with an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

I propose hereby two solutions that use the standard `for` syntax, both are using the great package [*progress*](https://cran.r-project.org/package=progress) from Gábor Csárdi and Rich FitzJohn

- 1) we can override temporarily or locally the `for` function to wrap around `base::for` and support progress bars.
- 2) we can define the unused `for<-`, and wrap around `base::for` using syntax `pb -> for(it in seq) {exp}` where `pb` is progress bar built with `progress::progress_bar$new()`.

Both solutions behave as standard for calls :

- The values changed at the previous iteration are available
- on error the modified variables will have the value they had just before the error

I packaged my solution and will demo them below then will go through the code

---

## Usage

```
#devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/pbfor")
library(pbfor)
```

#### Using `pb_for()`

By default `pb_for()` will override the `for` function for one run only.

```
pb_for()
for (i in 1:10) {
  # DO SOMETHING
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

Using parameters from `progress::progress_bar$new()` :

```
pb_for(format = "Working hard: [:bar] :percent :elapsed", 
       callback = function(x) message("Were'd done!"))
for (i in 1:10) {
  # DO SOMETHING
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

#### Using `for<-`

The only restriction compared to a standard `for` call is that the first argument must exist and can't be `NULL`.

```
i <- NA 
progress_bar$new() -> for (i in 1:10) {
  # DO SOMETHING
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

We can define a custom progress bar, and maybe define it conveniently in an initialisation script or in one's R profile.

```
pb <- progress_bar$new(format = "Working hard: [:bar] :percent :elapsed", 
       callback = function(x) ("Were'd done!"))
pb  -> for (i in 1:10) {
  # DO SOMETHING
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
}
```

For nested progress bars we can use the following trick :

```
pbi <- progress_bar$new(format = "i: [:bar] :percent\n\n")
pbj <- progress_bar$new(format = "j: [:bar] :percent  ")
i <- NA
j <- NA
pbi  -> for (i in 1:10) {
  pbj  -> for (j in 1:10) {
    # DO SOMETHING
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
  }
}
```

note that due to operator precedence the only way to call `for<-` and benefit from the syntax of `for` calls is to use the left to right arrow ´->´.

---

## how they work

#### `pb_for()`

`pb_for()` creates a `for` function object in its parent environment, then the new `for` :

- sets up a progress bar
- modifies the loop content
- adds a `` `*pb*`$tick() `` at the end of the loop content expression
- feeds it back to `` base::`for` `` in a clean environment
- assigns on exit all modified or created variables to the parent environment.
- removes itself if `once` is `TRUE` (the default)

It's generally sensitive to override an operator, but it cleans after itself and won't affect the global environment if used in a function so I think it's safe enough to use.

#### `for<-`

This approach :

- doesn't override `for`
- allows the use of progress bar templates
- has an arguably more intuitive api

It has a few drawbacks however:

- its first argument must exist, which is the case for all assignment functions (`fun<-`).
- it does some memory magic to find the name of its first argument as it's [not easily done with assignment functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246432/get-name-of-x-when-defining-operator), this might have a performance cost, and I'm not 100% sure about the robustness
- we need the package *pryr*

What it does :

- find the name of the first argument, using a helper function
- clone the progress bar input
- edit it to account for the number of iterations of the loop (the length of the second argument of `for<-`

After this it's similar to what is described for `pb_for()` in the section above.

---

## The code

#### `pb_for()`

```
pb_for <-
  function(
    # all args of progress::progress_bar$new() except `total` which needs to be
    # infered from the 2nd argument of the `for` call, and `stream` which is
    # deprecated
    format = "[:bar] :percent",
    width = options("width")[[1]] - 2,
    complete = "=",
    incomplete = "-",
    current =">",
    callback = invisible, # doc doesn't give default but this seems to work ok
    clear = TRUE,
    show_after = .2,
    force = FALSE,
    # The only arg not forwarded to progress::progress_bar$new()
    # By default `for` will self detruct after being called
    once = TRUE) {

    # create the function that will replace `for`
    f <- function(it, seq, expr){
      # to avoid notes at CMD check
      `*pb*` <- IT <- SEQ <- EXPR <- NULL

      # forward all arguments to progress::progress_bar$new() and add
      # a `total` argument computed from `seq` argument
      pb <- progress::progress_bar$new(
        format = format, width = width, complete = complete,
        incomplete = incomplete, current = current,
        callback = callback,
        clear = clear, show_after = show_after, force = force,
        total = length(seq))

      # using on.exit allows us to self destruct `for` if relevant even if
      # the call fails.
      # It also allows us to send to the local environment the changed/created
      # variables in their last state, even if the call fails (like standard for)
      on.exit({
        vars <- setdiff(ls(env), c("*pb*"))
        list2env(mget(vars,envir = env), envir = parent.frame())
        if(once) rm(`for`,envir = parent.frame())
      })

      # we build a regular `for` loop call with an updated loop code including
      # progress bar.
      # it is executed in a dedicated environment and the progress bar is given
      # a name unlikely to conflict
      env <- new.env(parent = parent.frame())
      env$`*pb*` <-  pb
      eval(substitute(
        env = list(IT = substitute(it), SEQ = substitute(seq), EXPR = substitute(expr)),
        base::`for`(IT, SEQ,{
          EXPR
          `*pb*`$tick()
        })), envir = env)
    }
    # override `for` in the parent frame
    assign("for", value = f,envir = parent.frame())
  }
```

#### `for<-` (and `fetch_name()`)

```
`for<-` <-
  function(it, seq, expr, value){
    # to avoid notes at CMD check
    `*pb*` <- IT <- SEQ <- EXPR <- NULL
    # the symbol fed to `it` is unknown, R uses `*tmp*` for assignment functions
    # so we go get it by inspecting the memory addresses
    it_chr <- fetch_name(it)
    it_sym <-as.symbol(it_chr)

    #  complete the progress bar with the `total` parameter
    # we need to clone it because progress bars are environments and updated
    # by reference
    pb <- value$clone()
    pb$.__enclos_env__$private$total <- length(seq)

    # when the script ends, even with a bug, the values that have been changed
    # are written to the parent frame
    on.exit({
      vars <- setdiff(ls(env), c("*pb*"))
      list2env(mget(vars, env),envir = parent.frame())
    })

    # computations are operated in a separate environment so we don't pollute it
    # with it, seq, expr, value, we need the progress bar so we name it `*pb*`
    # unlikely to conflict by accident
    env <- new.env(parent = parent.frame())
    env$`*pb*` <-  pb
    eval(substitute(
      env =  list(IT = it_sym, SEQ = substitute(seq), EXPR = substitute(expr)),
      base::`for`(IT, SEQ,{
        EXPR
        `*pb*`$tick()
      })), envir = env)

    # because of the `fun<-` syntax we need to return the modified first argument
    invisible(get(it_chr,envir = env))
  }
```

helpers:

```
fetch_name <- function(x,env = parent.frame(2)) {
  all_addresses       <- sapply(ls(env), address2, env)
  all_addresses       <- all_addresses[names(all_addresses) != "*tmp*"]
  all_addresses_short <- gsub("(^|<)[0x]*(.*?)(>|$)","\\2",all_addresses)

  x_address       <- tracemem(x)
  untracemem(x)
  x_address_short <- tolower(gsub("(^|<)[0x]*(.*?)(>|$)","\\2",x_address))

  ind    <- match(x_address_short, all_addresses_short)
  x_name <- names(all_addresses)[ind]
  x_name
}

address2 <- getFromNamespace("address2", "pryr")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone for your kind answers! As none of those fit my wacky needs, I started to steal some pieces of the given answers and made up a quite customized version:

```
forp <- function(iis, .fun) {
    .fun <- paste(deparse(substitute(.fun)), collapse='\n')
    .fun <- gsub(' <- ', ' <<- ', .fun, fixed=TRUE)
    .fun <- paste(.fun, 'index.current <- 1 + index.current; setTkProgressBar(pb, index.current, label=paste( round(index.current/index.max*100, 0), "% ready!"))', sep='\n')
    ifelse(is.numeric(iis), index.max <- max(iis), index.max <- length(iis))
    index.current <- 1
    pb <- tkProgressBar(title = "Working hard:", min = 0, max = index.max, width = 300) 
    for (i in iis) eval(parse(text=paste(.fun)))
    close(pb)
}
```

This is quite lengthy for a simple function like this, but depends only on base (anf of course: tcltk) and has some nice features:

- can be used on expressions, not just functions,
- you do not have to use `<<-` in your expressions to update global environment, `<-` are replaced to `<<-` in the given expr. Well,this might be annoying for someone.
- can be used with non-numeric indexes (see below). That is why the code become so long :)

Usage is similar to `for` except for you do not have to specify the `i in` part and you have to use `i` as index in the loop. Other drawback is that I did not find a way to grab the `{...}` part specified after a function, so this must be included in the parameters.

**Example #1:** Basic use

```
> forp(1:1000, {
+   a<-i
+ })
> a
[1] 1000
```

Try it to see the neat progress bar on your computer! :)

**Example #2:** Looping through some characters

```
> m <- 0
> forp (names(mtcars), {
+   m <- m + mean(mtcars[,i])
+ })
> m
[1] 435.69
```

Comment: Just be careful, as `a <<- b` will be replaced with ` a<<<- b` :-(

Comment: That's true :) Thanks for pointing out @Carl Witthoft! I have updated my function according to this problem, thought thanks to this modification writing the expression part of the `forp` function will require the user to use properly formatted syntax (leaving a space before and after the `<-`).